# RegularExpressionValidator for FIleUpload with AllowMultiple attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, file-upload

I have an `asp:FileUpload` control with the `AllowMultiple` option set to `true`.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="ucFileUploader" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true" Accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .jpe, .gif, .pdf, .doc, .xls, .txt, .docx, .xlsx, .pptx, .ppt, .png, .one, .rtf"/>
```

I also have a `RegularExpressionValidator` with a `ValidationExpression` to limit the files to specific file extensions.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ValidationExpression="(.jpg|.jpeg|.jpe|.gif|.pdf|.doc|.xls|.txt|.docx|.xlsx|.pptx|.ppt|.png|.one|.rtf)"
                                    ControlToValidate="ucFileUploader" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="One or more of the files you selected has an invalid file type." Display="Dynamic" />
```

The problem is that `RegularExpressionValidator` doesn't seem to apply itself to each filename individually.

For example, if I upload `test1.txt` and `badfile.exe` the regular expression will pass. If I upload just `badfile.exe` it will fail. If I upload `

How can I write my regular expression to validate against multiple files?

Note, this is purely for client-side purposes.

Answer (score -1):

here's one that seems to have worked (scroll down to see correct answer): https://forums.asp.net/t/1125353.aspx?RegularExpressionValidator+with+FileUpload+control+posting+error+after+upload
 hth

learn: 
https://regexone.com/ ||
https://qntm.org/files/re/re.html ||
etc.

Comment: This example does not use the `AllowMultiple` option of the `FileUpload` control.